# How can I complete a -N numeric parameter?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm writing an autocomplete script for `supervisorctl`.

Is it possible to complete a numeric parameter such as `-6`, `-999` etc?

Currently my call to `_arguments` looks like, which doesn't work:

```
_arguments \
  '--[last N bytes of process stdout]:number'
```

The first dash is the pattern to match, and the second dash indicates the argument must be in the same word.. But obv this clashes with a normal double dash argument.

EDIT: perhaps this will better explain what I want to do. The following illustrates what I want to happen at the cli:

```
> supervisorctl tail -<TAB>
 -- option --
-     -- last N bytes of process stdout
-f    -- Continuous tail of named process stdout
```

This above is what currently happens in my script. I select the first item in the option list, and get this:

```
> supervisorctl tail - <CURSOR>
```

I believe a trailing `-` will leave the cursor adjacent to the dash. How can I encode that in the parameter definition?

A work-in-progress for this can be found at:

https://github.com/mafrosis/zsh-completions/blob/supervisorctl/src/_supervisorctl

Comment: I don't understand: what would be the possible completions? Wouldn't any digit be valid at any point?

Comment: Correct. ZSH doesn't need to complete the number, but it does need to correctly prompt the user with the message and expect a number immediately after the dash.

Comment: @Gilles I've updated the question to be more specific